# How to delete files on Windows with Rapture IO

Tags: windows, scala, rapture.io

I'm writing Scala code. What is the correct path schema for writing a URI when using Rapture to operate with files on Windows? I have added the following dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.propensive" %% "rapture" % "2.0.0-M3" exclude("com.propensive","rapture-json-lift_2.11")
```

Here is part of my code:

```
import rapture.uri._
import rapture.io._
val file = uri"file:///C:/opt/eric/spark-demo"
file.delete()
```

but I got the message:

```
Error:(17, 16) value file is not a member of object rapture.uri.UriContext
val file = uri"file:///C:/opt/eric/spark-demo"
```

or I tried this one:

```
val file = uri"file://opt/eric/spark-demo"
```

The same error:

```
Error:(17, 16) value file is not a member of object rapture.uri.UriContext
val file = uri"file://opt/eric/spark-demo"
```

And my local path is:

```
C:\opt\eric\spark-demo
```

How can I avoid the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing an import:

```
import rapture.io._
import rapture.uri._
import rapture.fs._

val file = uri"file:///C:/opt/eric/spark-demo"
file.delete()
```

`rapture.fs` is the package defining an `EnrichedFileUriContext` implicit class, which is what the uri macro trys to build when being provided with a `file` URI scheme.